# How to fit a table in a one row?

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

I want to fit a table in same column, but it seemed cannot fit, i do not want making the font size smaller than my other text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Paired Differences}} \\
     \cmidrule{3-5}
     & & \small {\textbf{Mean (\%)}}
     & \thead{\small {\textbf{Std. Deviation}}\\ \textbf{(\%)}}& \thead{\small {\textbf{Std. Error}} \\ \textbf{Mean (\%)}} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Pair 1} & \textit{Testing exAple dataset} (BB) - \textit{Testing example dataset} (AA) 
    & 44.76 & 14.92 & 4.72  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Table 1}
    \label{tab:Table 1}
\end{table}






\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
% \begin{center}
    %\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}M*{6}{N}@{}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}c X c c c c c }
        \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference}}  &  \textbf{t}
      & \textbf {df} 
      & \textbf {Sig. (2-tailed)}  \\
     \cmidrule{3-4}  %\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
     & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} & & &\\
\midrule
    Pair 1 & \textit{Testing example dataset} (BB) - \textit{Testing Example Dataset} (AA) & 34.09\% &  55.44\% & 9.49 & 9 & .000\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Table 2}
    \label{tab:Table 2}
\end{table}
% \end{center}





\end{document}
```

[image]

I split the table into 2 which not good looking
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the code of your table as is?

Comment: What des "fit a table in a one row"  from your question title mean? Did you mean "column instead of "row"?  Also, you current document preamble will give you a one column document, so please clarify.

Comment: you have the  problem "how-to-put-elephant-to-lady-suitcase" ...

Comment: @Zarko That is easy, You open the suitcase and ask the elephant in a polite way to step in. It it much more challenging to fit a table wide into a too narrow column.

Comment: @Sveinung, good point :-). Apparently so far I have not been enough polite ... BTW, what to do with tables in such cases is extensive described in given link  to duplicate question (My table doesn't fit, ...). Also so far OP didn't provide code for her/his table.

Comment: @Zarko. I had editted my questions. Initially, i was thinking anyway to squeese the table in a row.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I had edited my question and posted my codes

Comment: @aan Thanks, voted to reopen

Comment: @ann, sorry, but now, after your editing of the question,  it become unclear. Do you like to reproduce table showed in the first image? For this at least you should provide table code and explain, where is the problem, that solutions in given link not help you. If you not like to have this table, but two new different table, than please ask new question